# Cannot convert value of type '[Document]' to expected argument type 'Binding<C>'

Tags: generics, swiftui, foreach

This error **Cannot convert value of type '[Document]' to expected argument type 'Binding'** occurs in the nested `ForEach` loop. My idea is to drill down into the arrays until I can access a property.

Here's the code:

**Model**

```
import Foundation

struct Publisher: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var username: String
    var documents: [Document]
}

struct Document: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var username: String
    var userImage: String
    var text: String
    var date: Date
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
import Foundation

final class PublisherViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var publishers = [
        Publisher(
            username: "blah",
            documents: [Document(
                title: "Blah Strikes Again",
                description: "How Blahs Work",
                username: "blah",
                userImage: "blah",
                text: "Enim porro et eius et. Recusandae nisi aperiam tenetur dolore ut ratione. Repudiandae quas sit est molestiae exercitationem non sequi et.",
                image: "",
                audio: "",
                video: "",
                date: Date())
    ]
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct PublisherDetailView: View {
   
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = PublisherViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
       HStack {
          ForEach(viewModel.publishers) { publisher in
              ForEach(publisher.documents) { document in // <-- **error here**
                  Text(document.content)
                      .padding()
                  Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've read a few posts on nested `ForEach` loops and most of them were errors in trying to loop over a single property versus an array (or in some cases a dictionary).

I'm guessing this is allowed by Swift. I also assume the compiler thinks I want to use a `<Binding>` because it doesn't recognize my array/implementation?

Not sure what **Generic parameter 'C' could not be inferred` means either**.

Answer (score -1):

**Figured it Out**

I was using the `id` parameter. But now my views are all funky, but that's a different problem.

Comment: How did u fix this